# Python 3.7: How to avoid stackoverflow for this recursive approach?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tail-recursion

#### 1. The situation

I'm working on a project in Python, and I got the following style of functions quite a lot:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import functools

...

    def myfunc(self, callback, callbackArg):
        '''
        This function hasn't finished its job when it hits the
        return statement. Provide a callback function and a
        callback argument, such that this function will call:
            callback(callbackArg)
        when it has finally finished its job.
        '''
        def start():
            myIterator = iter(self.myList)
            QTimer.singleShot(10, functools.partial(process_next, myIterator))
            return

        def process_next(itemIterator):
            try:
                item = next(itemIterator)
            except StopIteration:
                finish()

            # Do something

            QTimer.singleShot(10, functools.partial(process_next, myIterator))
            return

        def finish():
            callback(callbackArg)
            return

        start()
        return
```

This function won't take a long time to run, so it won't freeze the GUI and other processes. Instead, the function exits almost immediately and does its work later on in a lot of short bursts. Finally - when the job is done - it calls the provided callback.

#### 2. The problem

But there's a downside. This approach puts quite a strain on the stack (I think), because you got the following chain:

```py
start() -> process_next() -> process_next() -> process_next() -> ... -> finish()
```

Although I'm not entirely sure about that. The function `process_next()` calls `QTimer.singleShot(...)` and then exits. So maybe this long chain on the stack is not happening at all?

Do you know if the approach poses a risk for stack overflow? Are there any other potential risks I didn't discover yet?

**EDIT**
Thank you @ygramoel for clarifying. So in fact, the following line:

```py
QTimer.singleShot(10, functools.partial(process_next, myIterator))
```

calls the function `process_next(myIterator)` without pushing another stack frame. Therefore, I do not risk stack overflow with long lists. Great!

I was just wondering: Sometimes I don't want a few milliseconds delay as provided with the `QTimer.singleShot()` function. To call the next function immediately (without pushing another stack frame), I could do:

```py
QTimer.singleShot(0, functools.partial(process_next, myIterator))
```

However, each `QTimer.singleShot()` call fires a `pyqtSignal()`. Firing too many of them in a short timespan stretches the main thread to its limits (remember: the main python thread listens for incoming pyqt signals). The main thread processes the event queue entries one-by-one, calling the corresponding slots. So if the software fires too many events into that queue, the GUI might become unresponsive.

Is there another elegant way to call `process_next(myIterator)` without any of the following problems:

- Clogging the event queue such that the GUI gets unresponsive.
- Overflowing the stack with recursive function frames.

Comment: Is there an error message which makes you think it runs out of stack space?

Comment: I did have a few crashes mentioning the `recursion depth` was too deep. Because the actual functions in the project are more complicated than the sample above, I'm not sure if it would apply on this sample also.

Comment: It's not recursive, because `QTimer.singleShot` is (I assume) returning immediately, rather than calling `process_next` and waiting for *it* to return before returning. I don't know what `self.foo` might be doing with `process_next`, though.

Comment: @chepner, that makes sense. I hope you're right. But since `QTimer` invokes an inner function, shouldn't the context of that inner function be saved somewhere? If yes, wouldn't that be on the stack? [PS: don't worry about `foo()`. Maybe I should remove it.]

Comment: The context might be a stack-like structure, but it would be copied into the heap, not kept on the call stack. Also, the variables in the context are determined *statically*; only their *values* depend on the run-time context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not include the code for `item.foobar` and `self.foo`.  Assuming that these calls do not cause deep recursion, the maximum stack depth during execution of this code will not increase with the length of the list.

`functools.partial` does not immediately call the `process_next` function. It only creates a function-like object that can be called later.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html

`QTimer.singleShot` does not immediately call the `process_next` function either. It schedules the function-like object returned from `functools.partial` to be executed later, after the current call to `process_next` has returned.

You can easily verify this for yourself by putting a `print("enter")` statement at the beginning of `process_next` and a `print("leave")` statement just before the return.

On case of recursion,  you will see:

```
enter
enter
enter
...
leave
leave
leave
```

and the stack will overflow for very long lists.

If there is no recursion,  you will see:

```
enter
leave
enter
leave
enter
leave
...
```

and the maximum stack depth is independent of the length of the list.